# Создание временного окна (Окно уведомлений)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Необходимо создать такое окно, которое откроется, отобразиться пару секунд и само закроется. 
По сути это окно будет выполнять роль уведомления. 
Произошло событие - всплыло уведомление, отобразилось на пару секунд и скрылось. 
Текст в уведомлении каждый раз разный. 
Передавать буду как аргумент конструктора, либо через DataContext.

```
AlarmWindow alarm = new AlarmWindow(alarmMessage);
alarm.Show();
//либо
AlarmWindow alarm = new AlarmWindow()
{
    DataContext = alarmMessage
};
alarm.Show();
```

Comment: в c# не силен, но могу посоветовать гуглить по словам hud dialog

Comment: @PavelGridin к сожалению, по такому запросу выдаёт лишь диалоговые окна, которые подразумевают ожидание ответа от пользователя.. не то совсем

Comment: не не, hud (head up display) это типа как в iphone черные диалоги затухающие с прогрессом или сообщением, вот например https://github.com/yy1300326388/SimpleHUD, но для андроид

Comment: @PavelGridin я примерно догодался о чём вы, но я о том, что подобный запрос в гугле лично мне не помог

Comment: Хотя конечно настоящий HUD это дисплей на лобовом стекле, но вот почему то прижилось для временных сообщений

Comment: `alarm.Show(); await Task.Delay(2000); alarm.Close();` Не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал.. почему-то окна не закрывается =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно работать так:

```
void TickHandler(...)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            AlarmWindow alarm = new AlarmWindow(alarmMessage);
            alarm.Show();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            alarm.Close();
        });
}
```

Comment: предлагает перед `Application` поставить `await`. Стоит?

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Не, не откомпилируется.

Comment: заработало) спасибо

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в форму таймер с интервалом задаваемым через конструктор. И по событию таймера закрывайте форму изнутри.

```
partial class AlarmWindow:Form{

public AlarmWindows(string msg, int timeToShow){
...
System.Timers.Timer closeMe = new System.Timers.Timer((double)timeToShow);
closeMe.Elapsed += closeMe;
closeMe.AutoReset = false;
closeMe.Start();
...
}
void closeMe(object sender, System.Timers.Timer e){
this.close();
}
```

Comment: У меня WPF, а не WinForm, так что не формы, а окна.. но мысль я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Помог следующий способ:

```
AlarmWindow alarm = new AlarmWindow(alarmMessage);
alarm.Show();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // (!) вешает программу на 2 секунды, 
alarm.Close();            //поэтому в основном потоке использовать крайне не рекомендуется
```

**Так делать не стоит!!!** Вот [>тут<](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666019/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/666407#666407) есть более корректный ответ.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` o_O

Comment: Вы ж вешаете вашу программу на 2 секунды. Почему не `await Task.Delay(2000);`?

Comment: @VladD программу я точно не вешаю, так как всё это происходит в обработчике таймера. Да и ваш способ мне уже предлагали - он не сработал - окно не закрывалось =/

Comment: А вы попробуйте в течение этих двух секунд провести мышью над активными элементами и посмотрите, происходит ли hover-эффект.

Comment: @VladD не совсем понял что вы пытаетесь сказать. Уведомление должно приходить, даже если основное окно скрыто (свёрнуто в трей).

Comment: Ну вот чем отличается висящее приложение от невисящего? Например тем, что когда вы проведёте мышью над кнопкой, она меняет цвет.

Comment: @VladD сейчас обратил внимание, что действительно виснет.. странно, учитывая, что обработка Tick таймера, по идее, должна обрабатываться в отдельном потоке. Разве нет?

Comment: а при использовании `await Task.Delay(2000);` окно открывается и не закрывается... ни через 2 секунды, ни через 10

Comment: А если код с открытием/закрытием окна запускать в UI-потоке? Должно работать.

Comment: @VladD и как вы предлагаете это сделать? Обработчик Tick у меня мониторит процессы на событие (запущен видеоплеер с названием сериала, который есть в БД). В случае нахождения, он выводит уведомление..

Comment: Написал отдельным ответом.